# PHP PDO - Using Constant variable undefined when instantiating PDO object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using *PDO* on *Windows 7* using *XAMPP* 3.2.1 and I am having issues making it work, even though it works on my shared hosting server.

**settings.php**

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'testdb'); //DB Name
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); //DB host
define('DB_USER','root'); //DB user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ''); //DB users password
?>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php

require_once("settings.php");

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8',      DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

?>
```

**output.php**

```
<?php

require_once("db.php");

function outPutPosts(){
    return $db->query("select * from replies limit 35"); <-- this line
}

?>
```

The error it presents:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: db in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolplatform\output.php on line 10
>
> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function query() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolplatform\output.php on line 10

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: check this http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-querying-data-from-mysql-table/

Answer (score 1):

this issue is because the $db cant be acccessed directly inside function.you can use global keyword to access it inside your function like this:

```
function outPutPosts(){
 $db= $_GLOBAL['db'];
 return $db->query("select * from replies limit 35"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside db.php

```
<?php

require_once("settings.php");

function getConnection() {
       global $db;
       $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8',      DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
       $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
       return $db;
}
?>
```

Then output.php

```
<?php

require_once("db.php");

function outPutPosts(){
    getConnection();

    return $db->query("select * from replies limit 35"); 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable `$db` in your later function like this:

```
 <?php

    require_once("db.php");

    function outPutPosts(){
        $db = getConnection(); // define the variable $db here

        return $db->query("select * from replies limit 35"); 
    }

?>
```